# Restrictions on using Local-Variable Type Inference in java 10

Tags: java, java-10

Java 10 has introduce **Local-Variable Type Inference** feature [JEP-286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

We can use Local-Variable Type Inference using `var` which is *reserved type name*

But there are some restrictions of using it.

Can someone please summarise in which cases i will be not able to use var ?

Comment: Too broad? Interesting reads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154458/why-are-compound-definitions-using-var-not-allowed; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134118/array-initializer-needs-an-explicit-target-type-why;

Comment: the intentions is not to get into why it's not allowed , rather than just to note down whats not allowed. not sure if it is too broad and deserved to be close

Comment: IT's very well explained in the link you shared under `Risks and Assumptions` section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** As the name suggests, you can use it only for **local variables.**

**2.** Local type inference cannot be used for variables with no initializers

e.g Below code will not work

**Case 1:**

```
  var xyz = null;
            ^
  (variable initializer is 'null')
```

**Case 2:**

```
var xyz;
            ^
  (cannot use 'val' on variable without initializer)
```

**Case 3:**

```
   var xyz = () -> { };
            ^
  (lambda expression needs an explicit target-type)
```

**3.** Var can not used to instantiate multiple variables on same line

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154458/why-are-compound-definitions-using-var-not-allowed)  Suggested by nullpointer

```
   var X=10,Y=20,Z=30 // this is not allowed
```

**4: Var as Parameters**

```
   3.1 var would not be available for method parameters.

   3.2 Var would not be available for constructor parameters.

   3.3 Var would not be available for method return types.

   3.4 Var would not be available for catch parameters.
```

**4. Array initializer** is not allowed 
        More details can by found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134118/array-initializer-needs-an-explicit-target-type-why) Suggested by  Nicolai

```
var k = { 1 , 2 };
        ^   
(array initializer needs an explicit target-type)
```

**5. Method reference**  is not allowed

```
var someVal = this::getName;  
 error: cannot infer type for local variable nameFetcher
  (method reference needs an explicit target-type)
```

Comment: You might want to add could add array initializers.

Comment: ...and method reference as well as sampled in the [JEP-286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) risks and assumptions... and the interesting part of **why** each one of them seems to be too broad.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolai Added array intializers

Comment: How could `var` theoretically apply to return types?

Comment: @shmosel `var foo() { return ""; }` (you said “*theoretically*”)…

Comment: I felt it might be useful to show happy path examples, so I've included this [link from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/language/local-variable-type-inference.html).